# C++ How to remove class member field at compile time based on some condition?

Tags: c++, templates, field, compile-time, enable-if

I need to have a way to remove a class member field at compile time based on some condition. I've been trying a few things, such as this:

```
template <bool Condition, class FieldType> struct Conditional { FieldType Value; };
template <class FieldType> struct Conditional<false, FieldType> {};
```

But my problem is that members declared this way still use space on the total class size. My goal is **to reduce total class size** by removing some members depending on compile time condition. Is this possible **without class inheritance**?

I have access to C++20 if that matters.

Comment: An instance of `Conditional` in this case [can't be 0 bytes in size even if it has zero members](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo): "*The size of any object or member subobject (unless `[[no_unique_address]]` -- see below) is required to be at least 1 even if the type is an empty class type (that is, a class or struct that has no non-static data members), in order to be able to guarantee that the addresses of distinct objects of the same type are always distinct.*"

Comment: Actually it can, in C++20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address

Comment: As ugly and unexciting as it may be, the preprocessor is probably still going to be the most straightforward solution to this problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, `[[no_unique_address]]` will only work on a member, thus defeating the purpose of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, you apply like `[[no_unique_address]] Conditional<someCond_v<T>, SomeType> m_member;`.

Comment: @Jarod42 if `Condition == false`, then the empty struct (even with `[[no_unique_address]]`) will still take 1 byte. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/sKzj5xPGn

Comment: Minimal size of whole struct is 1, try with extra parameter to see the optimization [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fKeoPezqM).

Comment: You cannot reduce the total size of the top-level struct to zero.

Comment: You are right! Argh, I completely missed that! Sorry it's been a long week...

Comment: The only drawback with using this pattern with `[[no_unique_address]]` in C++20, is that you will still get size of 1 byte for top-level structs if it doesn't have members already, in which case you have to fallback on EBO if you want to keep it zero size.

Answer (score 2):

I know I have been asking **without class inheritance**, but it seems like [Empty Base Optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) is the only way I could find to do this. To achieve this, I did it this way:

Create two structs, one with the value, one empty:

```
struct Empty {};
struct SomeField { int something };
```

And have the class that I want to enable/disable a member field based on some compile time condition derive from `std::conditional_t`:

```
template <class T>
class SomeClass : private std::conditional_t<some_condition<T>, SomeField, Empty> { ... }
```

Not the best, but it does achieve my goal of reducing the total class size.